# Grabbing and storing DOM values to multidimentional array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am building a page which dynamically loads 'entry's with multiple fields (`textarea`, `time_from`, `time_until`).

I need somehow to think of the way with jQuery to grab those 'entry' multiple fields and store them in two dimensional array that I could pass with ajax  to server side.

What I have:

```
<div class="entry" id="1">
    <textarea class="report_actions">Entry1</textarea>
    <input class="time_from report_actions" value="2015-05-03 17:13">
    <input class="time_until report_actions" value="2015-06-18 17:13">
</div>

<div class="entry" id="2">
    <textarea class="report_actions">Entry1</textarea>
    <input class="time_from report_actions" value="2015-05-03 17:13">
    <input class="time_until report_actions" value="2015-06-18 17:13">
</div>
```

I am able to get everything in one array with the following:

```
var actions = $.makeArray($('.entry').find('.report_actions').map(function(index){ return $(this).val(); }));
```

But this grabs all values and makes 1-dimensional array. Two ideas coming to my mind. But I lack of knowledge to make them true therefore I though I'll turn them into questions.

- How can I upgrade command I have, to nest one array into another?
- How can I split array I have. i.e.([1,2,3,4,5,6]) -> ([1,2,3],[4,5,6])

EDIT: Thanks to `@tymeJV` this is what did the trick. Calling with `alert(values[x][y])` now I can pull the value I want

```
var values = $('.entry').map(function(){
    return [$(this).find('.report_actions').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get()];
}).get();

alert(values[0][2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two `.map` functions:

```
var values = [];
$(".entries").each(function() {
    var childValues = $(this).children().map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    values.push(childValues);
})
```

Should create a 2D array, each with 3 values for each `input` under `entries`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ggm866u4/

Edit: With 2 `.map` calls, you have to wrap the second `.map` in an array, since it'll auto-flatten:

```
var values = $('.entry').map(function(){
    return [$(this).find('.report_actions').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get()];
}).get();
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Not sure, maybe I adapted your script in the wrong way(see edit), but when I call alert(values) I still get all of the values in one list. Perhaps I should enhance it with makeArray?

Comment: @user3501968 -- Ahh, doesn't look like it'll work how I wanted, it's flattening them to a single array :\

Comment: you have made my day! this worked perfectly. Will edit the original post. A pity this is my first post and I can't +rep you :/